# Oracle - how to select and order by grouping n rows with sum of them between a and b

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to select and order by grouping n rows with sum of them between a and b?

I have the list number like:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12...100

```
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100
```

I need to order a group of each 5rows have 80 <= sum <= 100

1,12,22,23,31,   2,3,15,24,47,   5,11,17,26,37,   ...

Inside:

```
sum(1,12,22,23,31) = 89 match the condition
sum(2,3,15,24,45) = 91 match the condition
sum(5,11,17,26,37) = 96 match the condition
...
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: The general case of this problem is a bin packing problem; it is NP-hard and there not an easy solution. You will need to find a constraint-based solver or a bin-packing algorithm and implement it in PL/SQL and it will not be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is impossible.

- You have the numbers `1` to `100`.
- You want to split the numbers into groups with 5 numbers in each group.
- You want the groups to total between `80` and `100`.

If you start with the largest number `100` then it will immediately fill a group and there will be no room for anything else so there cannot be 5 items in that group without violating the maximum size constraint.

---

## Alternative:

If you want to:

- Pack the items into `n` bins;
- Pack the items in order from largest-to-smallest;
- Pack the items so that they always go into the most empty bin.

Then you can define the data types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list AS TABLE OF INT;

CREATE TYPE bin AS OBJECT(
  id    INT,
  items int_list,
  total INT,
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION bin(id IN INT) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
  MEMBER PROCEDURE add_item(item IN INT)
);

CREATE TYPE BODY bin AS
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION bin(id INT) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  IS
  BEGIN
    self.id := id;
    self.items := INT_LIST();
    self.total := 0;
    RETURN;
  END;
  
  MEMBER PROCEDURE add_item(item IN INT)
  IS
  BEGIN
    self.items.EXTEND;
    self.items(self.items.COUNT) := item;
    self.total := self.total + item;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE TYPE bin_table AS TABLE OF bin;
```

Then the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION bin_packing(
  items    IN INT_LIST,
  num_bins IN PLS_INTEGER
) RETURN bin_table DETERMINISTIC
IS
  sorted_items INT_LIST;
  bins         BIN_TABLE := BIN_TABLE();
  current_bin  BIN       := NULL;
  idx          PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
  BULK COLLECT INTO sorted_items
  FROM   TABLE(items)
  ORDER BY COLUMN_VALUE DESC;
  
  bins.EXTEND(num_bins);
  FOR i IN 1 .. num_bins LOOP
    bins(i) := NEW bin(i);
  END LOOP;

  FOR i IN 1 .. sorted_items.COUNT LOOP
    idx := 1;
    bins(1).add_item(sorted_items(i));
    current_bin := bins(1);
    WHILE idx < num_bins AND current_bin.total > bins(idx + 1).total LOOP
      bins(idx) := bins(idx+1);
      idx := idx + 1;
    END LOOP;
    IF idx > 1 THEN
      bins(idx)  := current_bin;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  
  RETURN bins;
END;
/
```

Then, if you want to pack the numbers 1 to 100 into 5 bins you can use the query:

```sql
SELECT id,
       total,
       (SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_VALUE, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY COLUMN_VALUE)
        FROM   TABLE(b.items)
       ) As items
FROM   bin_packing(
         ( SELECT CAST( COLLECT(LEVEL) AS int_list)
           FROM   DUAL
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100),
         5
       ) b
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | TOTAL | ITEMS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1010 | 1,10,11,20,21,30,31,40,41,50,51,60,61,70,71,80,81,90,91,100 |
> | 2 | 1010 | 2,9,12,19,22,29,32,39,42,49,52,59,62,69,72,79,82,89,92,99 |
> | 3 | 1010 | 3,8,13,18,23,28,33,38,43,48,53,58,63,68,73,78,83,88,93,98 |
> | 4 | 1010 | 4,7,14,17,24,27,34,37,44,47,54,57,64,67,74,77,84,87,94,97 |
> | 5 | 1010 | 5,6,15,16,25,26,35,36,45,46,55,56,65,66,75,76,85,86,95,96 |

If you wanted the numbers 1 to 100 into 7 bins then you can change the number of bins:

```sql
SELECT id,
       total,
       (SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_VALUE, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY COLUMN_VALUE)
        FROM   TABLE(b.items)
       ) As items
FROM   bin_packing(
         ( SELECT CAST( COLLECT(LEVEL) AS int_list)
           FROM   DUAL
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100),
         7
       ) b
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | TOTAL | ITEMS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 721 | 5,14,19,28,33,42,47,56,61,70,75,84,89,98 |
> | 4 | 721 | 6,13,20,27,34,41,48,55,62,69,76,83,90,97 |
> | 5 | 721 | 7,12,21,26,35,40,49,54,63,68,77,82,91,96 |
> | 6 | 721 | 8,11,22,25,36,39,50,53,64,67,78,81,92,95 |
> | 7 | 721 | 9,10,23,24,37,38,51,52,65,66,79,80,93,94 |
> | 2 | 722 | 1,4,15,18,29,32,43,46,57,60,71,74,85,88,99 |
> | 1 | 723 | 2,3,16,17,30,31,44,45,58,59,72,73,86,87,100 |

*(Note: as you can see, it is impossible to equally split the items into 7 bins as 7 is not a factor of the sum of the item values.)*

If you want to split the items so that there are about 5 items in each bin then you can calculate the number of bins:

```sql
WITH items ( item ) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100
)
SELECT id,
       total,
       (SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_VALUE, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY COLUMN_VALUE)
        FROM   TABLE(b.items)
       ) As items
FROM   bin_packing(
         ( SELECT CAST( COLLECT(item) AS int_list) FROM items ),
         ( SELECT CEIL( COUNT(item)/5 ) FROM items )
       ) b
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | TOTAL | ITEMS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 20 | 243 | 1,40,41,80,81 |
> | 19 | 244 | 2,39,42,79,82 |
> | 18 | 245 | 3,38,43,78,83 |
> | 17 | 246 | 4,37,44,77,84 |
> | 16 | 247 | 5,36,45,76,85 |
> | 15 | 248 | 6,35,46,75,86 |
> | 14 | 249 | 7,34,47,74,87 |
> | 13 | 250 | 8,33,48,73,88 |
> | 12 | 251 | 9,32,49,72,89 |
> | 11 | 252 | 10,31,50,71,90 |
> | 10 | 253 | 11,30,51,70,91 |
> | 9 | 254 | 12,29,52,69,92 |
> | 8 | 255 | 13,28,53,68,93 |
> | 7 | 256 | 14,27,54,67,94 |
> | 6 | 257 | 15,26,55,66,95 |
> | 5 | 258 | 16,25,56,65,96 |
> | 4 | 259 | 17,24,57,64,97 |
> | 3 | 260 | 18,23,58,63,98 |
> | 2 | 261 | 19,22,59,62,99 |
> | 1 | 262 | 20,21,60,61,100 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fe1acc3dcd339144fbb99e2e843e0367)*

Comment: But what if it is not necessary to use all the numbers and we only bother about groups of five numbers even if some numbers have to be left out?

Comment: @AmanSinghRajpoot That is not the OP's requirement .... the OP's requirement is impossible to solve. Other similar problems without all the constraints of the OP's problems are solvable (but, as I commented on the question, are NP-hard) but then we would not be solving the OP's problem.

Comment: @MT0, how about if the problem changes to spread a list of 100 numbers into groups with 5 numbers in each group and have the same total?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is impossible.

But I have a solution if you don't want to cover all the values in the column.

If it is not helpful to you, may be helpful for others who have a similar problem like yours.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PACKAGE ffes_pkg AS

       TYPE numtab is table of NUMBER;
       FUNCTION FFES RETURN numtab PIPELINED ;

end;
```

```
CREATE or REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ffes_pkg AS

 FUNCTION FFES RETURN numtab PIPELINED AS

       n PLS_INTEGER;
       flag BOOLEAN := FALSE ;
       v_num ffes_pkg.numtab;
       i INT := 1; j INT := 1; k INT := 1; l INT := 1; m INT := 1;
      
       BEGIN

       SELECT count(*) into n FROM NUMBERS;
       SELECT num BULK COLLECT into v_num FROM NUMBERS ORDER BY num;

       for q in 1..n LOOP
           WHILE i <= (n - 4 )LOOP   j := i +1;
                 WHILE j <= (n - 3 )LOOP  k := j + 1;
                      WHILE k <= (n - 2 )LOOP l := k + 1;
                          WHILE l <= (n - 1 )LOOP m := l + 1;
                                WHILE m <= (n)LOOP

                               if( v_num(i) <> 0 AND  v_num(j) <> 0 AND  v_num(k) <> 0 AND  v_num(l) <> 0 AND  v_num(m) <> 0  ) then
                                    if( (v_num(i) +  v_num(j) +  v_num(k) +  v_num(l) +  v_num(m) ) BETWEEN 80 AND 100) THEN

                                      PIPE ROW (v_num(i)); v_num(i) := 0;
                                      PIPE ROW (v_num(j)); v_num(j) := 0;
                                      PIPE ROW (v_num(k)); v_num(k) := 0;
                                      PIPE ROW (v_num(l)); v_num(l) := 0;
                                      PIPE ROW (v_num(m)); v_num(m) := 0;

                                    flag := TRUE ;

                                    END IF;
                                END IF;

                           m := m + 1;
                         if (flag) THEN  EXIT ;  END IF; END LOOP;
                         l := l + 1;
                       if (flag) THEN EXIT ;  END IF; END LOOP;
                     k := k + 1;
                    if (flag) THEN EXIT ;  END IF; END LOOP;
                    j := j + 1;
                  if (flag) THEN EXIT ;  END IF; END LOOP;
                  i := i + 1;
               if (flag) THEN EXIT ;  END IF; END LOOP;

          i := 1;
          flag := FALSE;
     end LOOP ;
  END;
END;
```

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(ffes_pkg.FFES());
```

Time complexity is huge for this solution around O(n^6)

Comment: This does not output anything when the `NUMBERS` table has 10 items [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b7dd6b935f982fa59e1449c47d89cbcd).

Comment: Sum has to be between 80 and 100. 1 to 10 doesn't make sum 80

Comment: I tried with a table of 100 items and the query timed out on the db<>fiddle.

Comment: Time complexity is high. It works on my local system.

Comment: May ttake some hours

Comment: sorry, some years.  it works with 50,  (1
2
3
24
50
4
5
6
16
49
7
8
9
10
46
11
12
13
14
30
15
17
18
19
20
)

Comment: 100 makes it 100 00 00 00 00 00 00